# Using jquery to replace a specific word inside template literal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Is it possible to replace a specific word inside a template literal.
For instance, `${Group[1].Names[1].NickName)}` 
and I do something similar as `$('#someDiv').text((i, t) => t.replace('Nickname', 'CoolName'));`

Comment: When would this template literal be interpolated? I am guessing long before jQuery appears on the scene.

Comment: `$("#id").text(i, t) =>` implies that the literal has already been applied, so the text no longer contains 'Nickname' for it to be replaced.   Can you include more context, eg where/how the *literal* is defined and applied.