# Replacing a specific word within div after it being applied

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have got a div

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
            <div class="div">
              <div class="subdiv">
                <p>${Groups[0].Names[0].Nickname}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="div">
              <div class="subdiv">
                <p>${Groups[0].Names[1].Nickname}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
</html>
```

My goal is to replace "Nickname" with "Coolname" for each div after clicking a button, however the page loads up with Nickname by default and if I execute jquery `$('#subdiv p').text((i, t) => t.replace('Nickname', 'Coolname'));` it doesn't actually see "Nickname" but the output itself. Is there any simple workaround? preferably without jquery. I simply need to change Nickname with Coolname and then display it again as `Groups[0].Names[0].Coolname`

Comment: Are you using a templating language? `${Groups[0].Names[0].Nickname}` will not display the contents of that property in standard HTML, please add the relevant tag.

Comment: _"if I execute jquery `$('#subdiv p').text((i, t) => t.replace('Nickname', 'Coolname')); `it doesn't actually see "Nickname" but the output itself."_ - looks like you are using some client-side templating engine there. Which will probably already have gone over your document on page load, and replaced `${Groups[0].Names[0].Nickname}` with an actual value. So you can't "replace" `Nickname` then, if `Nickname` is already not there any more at that point.

Comment: Do the comments on your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75979857/using-jquery-to-replace-a-specific-word-inside-template-literal) help?

Comment: If it's a templating engine (which one?) then you might be able to get-in-first and make your replacements, there may be an event you can listen for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you are using a template engine in the backend. jQuery in the frontend does not know "Coolname" after rendering the HTML page. But you can specify this value in a data attribute and let jQuery access it.

In this example, nickname and coolname are not changed, but you could implement it like this or similar:

```js
window.addEventListener('click', (el) => {
  document.querySelectorAll('[data-coolname]').forEach((el) => {
    el.textContent = el.getAttribute('data-coolname');
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <div class="subdiv">
    <p data-coolname="${Groups[0].Names[0].Coolname}">${Groups[0].Names[0].Nickname}</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="div">
  <div class="subdiv">
     <p data-coolname="${Groups[0].Names[1].Coolname}">${Groups[0].Names[1].Nickname}</p>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="change">change</button>
```

Comment: This answers my question. Is there a non jquery way to it by a chance?

Comment: Thank you very much! but could you as well keep the jquery way too? both ways. (you removed the jquery way)

Comment: Look in the answer history. "edited ..." link under the answer.